# React Native: Collaborate document across app users

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In a web environment, we share documents, presentations (say using Google Docs, Google Sheet).The above assumes that all users are authenticated using Google OAuth2

How do we mimic the same in react native application. Note: Here user shouldn't have gmail account